# TypeScript: How to use generic types on abstract class as parameter type hints?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an abstract class:

```js
abstract class Connector<T> {
  abstract parse(theirData: T[]): OurData[]
}
```

However, concrete subclasses do not infer the method types from the type parameter:

```js
class APIConnector extends Connector<string> {
  // Parameter 'theirData' and return type implicitly has an 'any' type.
  parse(theirData) {
    ...
    return connection
  }
}
```

Maybe I am misunderstanding the purpose of TypeScript in this particular instance, but why would the inherited abstract methods not infer the type from the generics? It seems to defeat the point if I have to additionally type-hint the parameter and return types.

I understand that by using generics I am prevented from creating a bad signature for this method, but then if TS already knows what the type is then why would it state it as "implicit any"? Is this an option or something I can toggle in tsconfig?

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Oblosys. Seems like there's not much leeway going forward for a QoL update like this. I suppose at least you are prevented from making a completely incorrect method signature but I just really dislike the redundancy.